# import ReactCSSTransitionGroup in ES6 React Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using NPM to manage my packages and modules on my node.js app.

I have updated react to ^0.14.6 version and also installed ReactCSSTransitionGroups via npm.

Unfortunately uppon trying to use this addon in one of my child components I face the following error which says that its still undefined:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactCSSTransitionGroup is not defined
```

My implementation code:

```
import React from 'react';
import CSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';
```

Usage is within a maping function:

```
...
return(
   <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example">
      {Content}
   </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
);
...
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're importing `CSSTransitionGroup` but using `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`. Switch one or the other so the variable lines up.

Comment: oh... seems like it's been a long day. Thank you haha... I'll accept it as a answer in 2minutes.

Answer (score 15):

```
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react/lib/ReactCSSTransitionGroup';
```

you should import like this.

Comment: Can you explain this?